# Find count of unique in subclass

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data which looks like this

```
sample <- data.frame(DEPT = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),CLASS = c(1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2),SUBCLASS= c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1),ID = c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108))

> sample
  DEPT CLASS SUBCLASS  ID
1    1     1        1 101
2    1     1        1 102
3    1     1        2 103
4    1     2        2 104
5    2     1        1 105
6    2     1        1 106
7    2     2        1 107
8    2     2        1 108
```

By final data should look like this

```
> sample
  DEPT CLASS SUBCLASS  ID ITEM_SUBCLASS_COUNT
1    1     1        1 101                   2
2    1     1        1 102                   2
3    1     1        2 103                   1
4    1     2        2 104                   1
5    2     1        1 105                   2
6    2     1        1 106                   2
7    2     2        1 107                   2
8    2     2        1 108                   2
```

How can achieve this using dplyr?

Comment: What is `ITEM_SUBCLASS_COUNT` supposed to be? Guessing, probably `sample %>% group_by(DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS) %>% mutate(ITEM_SUBCLASS_COUNT = n())`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[,ITEM_SUBCLASS_COUNT := .N , .(DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS)]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sample$ITEM_SUBCLASS_COUNT <- with(sample, ave(seq_along(DEPT), DEPT, 
                                     CLASS, SUBCLASS, FUN = length))
```

Comment: why to "." before ` .(DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS)` is it instead of `list`?

Comment: @Pgibas  Yes, you are right.  It replaces the `list` command.

Comment: @Pgibas have a look at the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) if you're interested.